# Banner de aniversário não está na língua do site

Tags: bug, status-pronto

A iniciativa do banner é louvável, mas infelizmente ele não
está na língua do site:

[image: Banner com mensagem em inglês]

A string faz um tempo que já foi enviada para o traducir, mas
até o momento, não refletiu no banner (ou não era a mesma
string?)

"Bonus points" se algum designer aproveitar o momento e fizer
o clique no banner todo...

Answer (score 3):

A tradução foi publicada, e o banner já aparece assim:

[image: Banner com texto Feliz 10º Aniversário]